# what's unclear about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439213/ansible-ensure-that-a-given-file-or-path-exists

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61439213/ansible-ensure-that-a-given-file-or-path-exists) and answer were closed with "This question needs details or clarity" by 3 users, neither of which cared to give a reason or seem to be reachable for feedback.

I'm at a loss. What's unclear about the title, the question text or the answer? What am I supposed to do short of deleting the question and answer which I think are valuable (because I needed just that solution many times in practice)?

Also when giving a "-1" to someone, one is encouraged to leave a comment. So these three users are closing the question with no comment. How is that action valuable and not plain misconduct?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/3122701

Comment: I probably would have marked your question as a duplicate of the one mentioned in it, since it seems like you created the question for the sole purpose of posting an answer. Why not just post an answer on the previously posted question?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I have created the question so I can add the solution and people can find it. (which the stackoverflow interface encouraged me to do). I could add an answer to the previously posted question, however it wouldn't be an answer to the question asked there. My POV is that the referenced question has a correct answer and it shouldn't be poluted with irrelevant related context/data.

Comment: I see @HereticMonkey's comment recieved 3 ups. So I'll delete my question and and'll "pollute" the related question instead. I'm very surprised that is considered good practice here. Thanks a lot to you all for guidance.

Comment: You should probably wait until the question receives more traffic... I mean, my comment was just my opinion, and I might just be an outlier that three other people agreed with. It's only been a few minutes; Meta moves at a slower pace than the main site. It's obviously up to you. There are a diversity of opinions on Meta that deserve to be heard, even if I don't agree with them...

Comment: @HereticMonkey you mean this question here on SOMeta or the one that was closed?

Comment: This meta question. You can always reopen your own question if you delete it.

Comment: I have taken a look at the question you linked and I have to say it doesn't make much sense to me. Not because I don't know much about Ansible -- if I met what *I think* is a similar problem tomorrow, I may or may not understand what your question asks and what your answer answers. But it is very vague, and partially due to that, doesn't come across as useful for the knowledge base. Is it a niche? I wouldn't know. Perhaps there is a good generic question on Ansible hidden in your question, but you are best served editing it to improve matters, if you ask me. Same goes for the answer.

Comment: Thanks @amn . If I knew how to make the question or answer clearer then I would do it. So I'll just delete it.

Comment: I think you're selling yourself short here. What does "file exist" refer to with Ansible? What kind of file? Now, see, even without knowing much about Ansible, for me personally, I know what it is supposed to do, more or less. Orchestration. Files are involved -- scripts, configurations, etc. When you write "I need to make sure a file exists", what do you mean? What should fail when it doesn't? What do you mean by terse, exactly? Is there reason you can't afford extra 3 lines of verbosity? And last but not least -- there isn't any question marks in your question or its title.

Comment: @amd I'm not sure what is semantically unclear about the statement "a file does not exist". I also I think I shouldn't be explaining what Ansible is in a question specifically tagged as Ansible. And "failure" is well defined in Ansible, so again I think, I should *not* be explaining how Ansible is working for the generatl public but concentrate on the problem at hand. By "terse" I mean precisely [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terse). Wrt to why extra 3 lines can not be afforded: because they add cognitive load for no gain.

Comment: I mean, if all you're doing is answering the question in a separate post, it should've been closed as a duplicate instead. Post your answer on the original post instead of posting a new question to post a solution to that exact problem. Splitting it up because you have a different answer causes fragmentation and makes stuff harder to find - which is why we have duplicates in the first place. Finally, even if you self-answer a question, the question itself _has_ to be a real question with enough details, and be otherwise on-topic. A self-answer alone doesn't justify low-quality questions.

Answer (score 9):

> yes, I have created the question so I can add the solution and people can find it

I'm not understanding your thought process here. People have found (viewed) the other question 169k times! If they are finding the other question, is because it has the correct search terms to be found. What they *won't* find in that question is *your answer*, since you decided to post it in another question. I suggest to post it there so it can be found. People can always scroll down if they believe the answer doesn't fit their requirements.

Also, remember that self answering is under the same expectations as every question. Your answer does address [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35654286/792066), so post it there. There's no need to create another question.

Comment: On a related note, probably close voters were expecting a problem with the other question more thoughtful than "it's very verbose", since there are 10 proposed solutions and seemly all solve the problem.

Comment: it's not the same question. The problem that https://stackoverflow.com/q/35654286/792066 wants to solve is to check whether a file exists, register that knowledge and then do something based on that knowledge. That's not my problem. My problem is 1) that the solution presented there is very verbose (which matters, because the goal of code is *also* to transport semantics to its reader (and not just loads of syntax as those answer do)) and 2) I want to terminate *immediately*.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek aren't you aware that to terminate, you first need to know that the file exist? "then do something based on that knowledge" can be anything, even *terminate*. Your problem is actually two part: check that something exist, do something if that something exist. The question ask only the first thing. What you do after you check for the condition is open to you.